# Why Tailwind get border color from text-color class?

Tags: tailwind-css

I prepared some custom colors for my Tailwind project. When I using "border" class with "text-color" class, border has color of text color.

Additionally, using "border-color" class not respected.

Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/khYce8N9yU

How to set the same color of background and border and other color for text?

Answer (score 1):

That is because Tailwind [includes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#border-styles-are-reset-globally) `border-color` as `currentColor` in preflight styles

You may specify other default border color (for example to be red) like

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        borderColor: {
            DEFAULT: 'red'
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Maybe the /_preview of Tailwind incorrect show classes for borders like "border-red", "border-blue" when You prepare just colors, without setting "borderColor" in config?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understood what do you mean. But the general use case for borders in Tailwind is to use BOTH classes as `border` will set border-width and `border-color` - border color. But if you will use ONLY `border` it will be colored as default one

Comment: Like [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2Xy49aC1y1) second part - both buttons now have green border while in a first (no border color specified) - default current color